# How to create a shortcut in Rust using gtk4?

Tags: rust, callback, gtk, shortcut

I am trying to create a shortcut for my program in Rust using gtk4 (I am already using it for other stuff). I found the struct `Shortcut` and documentation says "It contains a description of how to trigger the shortcut via a `ShortcutTrigger` and a way to activate the shortcut on a widget via a `ShortcutAction`."
`Shortcut` has indeed a `new` function:

```
pub fn new(
    trigger: Option<impl IsA<ShortcutTrigger>>,
    action: Option<impl IsA<ShortcutAction>>
) -> Shortcut
```

For the trigger I simply wrote:

```
let shortcut_trigger = ShortcutTrigger::parse_string("<Control>S");
```

The problem is the `ShortcutAction`. I just want a function (let's say `my_function`) to be executed. It's a very simple function with no arguments and no return but the doc says:

"GTK provides various actions:

- `MnemonicAction`: a shortcut action that calls `gtk_widget_mnemonic_activate()`
- `CallbackAction`: a shortcut action that invokes a given callback
- `SignalAction`: a shortcut action that emits a given signal
- `ActivateAction`: a shortcut action that calls `gtk_widget_activate()`
- `NamedAction`: a shortcut action that calls `gtk_widget_activate_action()`
- `NothingAction`: a shortcut action that does nothing"

I think that my case is the `CallbackAction` but at this point I'm stuck and don't know how to write this. Should I wrap `my_function` in a `CallbackAction` one? How should I do it? I'm not so good at Rust but I'm getting lost in all the types, traits, lifetimes and stuff.

I tried changing `my_function` to make it fit into some `CallbackAction` function but it didn't work. I read that `CallbackAction` has a `new` function with a parameter but I can't quite understand how I should instantiate it. Also I tried using other libraries but since I am already using gtk I would prefer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `CallbackAction::new` is given as

```rust
pub fn new<P: Fn(&Widget, Option<&Variant>) -> bool + 'static>(
    callback: P
) -> CallbackAction
```

It takes a single argument, `callback`, which is `Fn(&Widget, Option<&Variant>) -> bool + 'static`. Let's take this apart.

The simple things first: `callback` takes the widget that activates the shortcut, and an optional argument as `&Variant`, which can be specified on `Shortcut::set_arguments`. It returns a bool (maybe for inhibit?).

The rest is important for [closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) that capture variables:
`Fn` means "function that can be called multiple times, without mutating the environment" and `'static` means that all references in the closure must be valid for the entire lifetime of the program.

The easiest way to achieve this is to move anything you capture into the closure.

If `my_function` takes no arguments:

```rust
let action = CallbackAction::new(|_,­_|{my_function();false})
```

If you need arguments, take a look at [`clone!`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/macro.clone.html) or at the [examples](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/tree/master/examples).